# Pages for products with a specific category in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

Hi I am trying to set up categories on my e-commerce website using Ruby on Rails, what I want to do is have pages which shows products from a specific category for example I have the category t-shirt so all t-shirts are shown etc… In the backend I am able to set a products category, as I have assigned a foreign key category_id to the products table and the the relationship in the models for the category is it has many products and for the products model it belongs to a category. What would I have to do for showing products from a specific category?

Here is my current code:

**Store controller**

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize

  def index
    @cart = current_cart
    @products = Product = Product.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
  end
end
```

**Category controller**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There's some very weird stuff happening with your code formatting, especially in `StoreController#index`.

Comment: Your code is still broken. `respond_to` isn't a class method, and `@product` wouldn't be anything in that context anyway. Notice you have 3 `end`s but are only 2 blocks of code deep? Looks like you're missing a method around the `respond_to` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no reason you can't use the collections Rails provides when you specify a one-to-many association:

```
@products = @category.products
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Presumably `@category` is nil at that time, then? Make sure it exists and is a Category.

Comment: Do I have to specify the category for example I have a category called  Top and which stored in the database as category_name:Top and  category_id:01 ?

Comment: Well, you could join the category, I suppose. e.g. `@products = Product.joins(:category).where('categories.name = ?', 'Top')` (assuming you're on Rails 3). I suppose that's nominally more efficient (one database query vs. two) if you don't need any data about the category itself....

Comment: That works fine when i am under the index but when it try to make a custom one like this                                               `code` def jeans
  @cart = current_cart
        @products = Product.joins(:category).where('category_name = ?', 'Jeans').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end `code`. I get this error Couldn't find Product with id=jeans ? What am I missing?

Comment: It seems unlikely that that error would result from the line in question. Is that where the error trace is pointing? It sounds like it's encountering something like `Product.find('Jeans')` or some such.

Comment: What it is doing is sending the result to this `code`   def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart = current_cart
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
`code` I get this full error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoreController#show

Couldn't find Product with id=jeans app/controllers/store_controller.rb:66:in `show'

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that `params[:id]` is the string 'Jeans', rather than an id number.

Comment: I get this error when trying what you suggested.`code` ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoreController#show

Couldn't find Product without an ID `code`